# get whole data of all rows in which checkbox is checked in telerik grid through jquery and store it in array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, checkbox

I am using Telerik grid in MVC 3 and I have a grid having some columns, and each row has a checkbox. On the submit of the Ok button I want all the data of the grid to be fetch, from the row in which the checkbox is checked. I want to get records of each column to be stored in a separate array. And I want to do this using a jquery.

What should I do for this?

I did something like this to get the count of checkboxes checked in a grid:

```
function getData() {
    debugger;
    var Records = $(':checked');
    var checkedRecords = Records.length - 2;
    if (checkedRecords < 1) {
        alert('Check a few checkboxes first.');
        return checkedRecords;
    }
    else {
        alert("RecordsChecked: " + checkedRecords);
    }
}
```

`getData()` is a function which will called on click of Ok button.

Please suggest me something...

This is my Telerik grid code:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<Model>()
        .Name("TelerikGrid")
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(
                            Html.Resource("Grid")))
                             .DataKeys(keys =>
                             {
                                 keys.Add(o => o.EmployeeID);
                             })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(m => m.EmployeeID)
                   .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='Employee1' onclick='return function1(this);' id='Employee1' />")
                columns.Bound(m => m.EmpFName).Title("F Name").ReadOnly(true).Width(65);
                columns.Bound(m => m.EmpLName).Title("L Name").ReadOnly(true).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(m => m.Task).Title("Task")
                    .ClientTemplate("<div id='textbox1'><input type='textbox' name='Task' id='Task' disabled='disabled' new { style='width:55px'} value='<#=Task#>' /></div>").Width(53);
            })
            .DataBinding(databinding => databinding
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Select("GetData", "Home”)
            )
        .Selectable()
        .Render();
    %>
```

Comment: Someone without knowledge of Telerik but good in jquery can answer this question if you post the markup of the grid. One row of the grid is enough.

Comment: Please add that to your question, and it would be best if you post the html that was created not the code, something like `<table><tr><td>..</td></tr>` or maybe it's an ul or div.

Comment: I am using Telerik grid, there is no such thing like <table> or <tr>, still i'll add my Grid code. Hope u can help me...

Comment: whatever tool you use, it will sure render some html element. I've worked with Telerik grid in webforms and I know it renders a table element. That's what I meant, show the rendered grid. And you can show just one row so you don't have to post too much code and other people here can get interested faster ;)

Comment: Thank u for quick reply...yes i have rendered this grid in my partial view page. i am adding that code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we understand each other. But I will give you an answer that works with a Telerik Grid rendered as a table. So suppose this is your grid:

```
<table cellspacing="0"><colgroup>
<col style="width:45px">
<col style="width:100px"><col style="width:200px"><col><col style="width:120px"></colgroup><tbody>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10248</td><td>Paul Henriot</td><td>59 rue de l'Abbaye</td><td>07/04/1996</td></tr>
<tr class="t-alt"><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10249</td><td>Karin Josephs</td><td>Luisenstr. 48</td><td>07/05/1996</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10250</td><td>Mario Pontes</td><td>Rua do Paço, 67</td><td>07/08/1996</td></tr>
<tr class="t-alt"><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10251</td><td>Mary Saveley</td><td>2, rue du Commerce</td><td>07/08/1996</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10252</td><td>Pascale Cartrain</td><td>Boulevard Tirou, 255</td><td>07/09/1996</td></tr>
<tr class="t-alt"><td><input type='checkbox' name='SelectedEmployee' id='SelectedEmployee' /></td><td>10253</td><td>Mario Pontes</td><td>Rua do Paço, 67</td><td>07/10/1996</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

So your grid has the following columns, in order, from left to right:

- the checkbox - **first** column
- the `id` of an employee - **second** column
- the `name` of an employee - **third** column

Now to answer your question:

> On the submit of the Ok button I want all the data of the grid to be
>   fetch, from the row in which the checkbox is checked

You can call a function that will build your array object in jquery like this:

```
function readGrid() {
    var employees = [];

    $('[name="SelectedEmployee"]:checked').each(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');                                
        var emp = {
            // we start at 2 because the first one is the checkbox
            // also it would be easier if you have an id for each of the column
            // and do this row.find('#idCol') / row.find('#nameCol')
            id: row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
            name: row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text(),
        };                
        employees.push(emp);
    });       
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur reply von v. but actually am not rendering my telerik grid as a table.bcoz data which is displaying in that grid comes through a query which is a combination of 2 3 tables.i hope u can understand my problem....and thnx for the answer

Comment: Even if it's not a table you can use my answer as a guide. I can change my answer that you can specifically you, only you have to tell me what is the rendered html of the grid. Is it divs, lis or what?

Comment: the grid code which i have added in my question is under <div> tag. am sorry if am unable to satisfy ur question needs

Comment: [This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid) of the Telerik mvc grid renders the grid as a table. That's where I actually got my sample data. If you look into that, you will probably understand my suggestion, if not, then sorry I can help no further. But let me just say again, if you follow my example, you can build your object array that way. Just select the elements you need to select an pull out the values from them and build the object array as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: yes u r right.I have tried it. This is working great for me. Thanx a lot for the answer,Realy thank u so much. :-)

Comment: It is working fine for the columns of a grid but it is not extracting data of textbox which is in ClientTemplate of the grid. Please suggest me something...

Comment: If the element you are trying to target has an id (and I suggest you give it an id and that it should be a unique id for that row) then do this: `row.find('the_id_of_the_element').val()`

Comment: I tried to do whatever u suggested... as shown in above code id of my textbox is Allocation. i tried somewhat like: `row.find('Allocation').val()`  but is displaying value of that textbox as undefined.

Comment: Don't forget the `#` - `.find('#Allocation')` ;)   [Know more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)